# Login no funciona

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de hacer un login, pero sobre el que estoy trabajando, no logro que funcione y me esta arrojando este error:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'catch' (T_CATCH) in C:\xampp\htdocs\bd\login.php on line 38**

Este es el código que estoy utilizando:

```
  <?php
    ini_set('display_errors','off');
    ini_set('display_startup_errors','off');
    error_reporting(0);

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];  

    function Conectarse()
    {
        if(!($link=mysqli_connect('localhost','','usuarios')))
        {
            echo "Error conectando a la bd.";
            exit();
        }
        if (!mysqli_select_db("usuarios",$link))
        {
            echo "error seleccionando la bd.";
            exit();
        }
        return $link;
    }
    $con = Conectarse();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'";
    $q = mysqli_query($query,$conexion);
    try{

        if(mysqli_result($q,0))
        { $result = mysqli_result($q,0);

        echo "Usuario validado correctamente";
    }else{
            echo "Usuario o Password erroneos";
    }catch(Exception $error){}
        mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: Bienevenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Es mucho mejor que coloques el codigo en formato texto que poner una imagen, pues así te podemos ayudar mejor y buscar una solución más rápida.  Espero el código.

Comment: Ya lo modifique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sencillo. Solo estas cerrando el `Else` y te falta cerrar el `Try` tambien. En la linea 38 (según tu texto) tienes

```
}catch(Exception $error){}
    mysqli_close($con);
```

añade otro } al principio y quedará así:

```
}}catch(Exception $error){}
        mysqli_close($con);
```

Con eso se eliminará el error.

Suerte!

Comment: Si, ya no me mostró el error, muchas gracias.